# Conditional declaration by array of records

Tags: modelica, dymola

I try to create many components depending on the value of constant elements. These elements are organized in an array of records.
Dymola prints the translation log for the example below:

[image]

But I'm sure to use fixed conditions because I only perform allowed operations on constant values.

Here is the simple example of what I wantet to do:

```
model ConditionalComponent
  type Enum = enumeration(one,two,three);

  record Tmp
    parameter Integer ID;
    parameter Boolean active;
  end Tmp;

  record TmpNamed
    parameter Enum name;
    extends Tmp;
  end TmpNamed;

  function reorder
    input TmpNamed inp[:];
    output Tmp out[size(inp,1)];
  algorithm 
    for elem in inp loop
      out[elem.name] := Tmp(elem.ID, elem.active);
    end for;
  end reorder;

  constant TmpNamed testIn[:] = {
    TmpNamed(Enum.two,20,true),
    TmpNamed(Enum.one,10,true),
    TmpNamed(Enum.three,30,true)};

  constant Tmp testOut1[:] = reorder({
    TmpNamed(Enum.two,20,true),
    TmpNamed(Enum.one,10,true),
    TmpNamed(Enum.three,30,true)});

  constant Tmp testOut2[:] = reorder(testIn);

  constant Boolean active1 = testOut1[Enum.one].active;
  constant Boolean active2 = testOut2[Enum.one].active;

  Real t1=0 if testOut1[Enum.one].active;
  //Real t2=0 if testOut2[Enum.one].active;
  //Real t3=0 if active1;
  //Real t4=0 if active2;
end ConditionalComponent;
```

The function *reorder* is intended to ease the management of large lists of named active components. Normally the constant *testOut2* is used and created within the package *ConditionalComponent*. But for testing purposes *ConditionalComponent* is a model here.  Actually I only want to use the line

```
Real t2=0 if testOut2[choice].active;
parameter Enum choice = Enum.one;
```

within other components, that have a *parameter* of type *Enum*. The declarations for t1, t3, t4 are only some tests that work, depending on what is left uncommented.
For example leaving the declaration for t1 and t3 uncommented works. But if one uses only the declaration for t1, it is not translated by Dymola.

The difference between t1 and t2 is, that the argument for reorder is passed directly or via the constant *testIn*.

I'm sure, that most *parameter* and *constant* prefixes are unnecessary and I tried hard to figure out the problem. But unfortunately I cannot decide whether Dymola is not working correctly or I did something wrong. And I've got no idea how to debug the translation process to figure it out by myself.

Can anyone tell me, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Not something wrong, but it's just currently seen as too complicated and not handled.

A work-around is to split subscripting and element access:

```
constant Tmp testOut1_one=testOut1[Enum.one];
Real t1=0 if testOut1_one.active;
```

Comment: I already implemented your suggested work-around

Comment: (`//Real t3=0 if active1;`). But it will not work if you want to iterate over testOut1 to conditionally (depending on active) connect components. Do you know the measure for complexity, that I exceeded?